# How can I get Visual Studio Deployment Project Properties values

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, setup-deployment, target-platform

[image]

How can I dynamically get TargetPlatform in deployment project properties or can i write targetPlatform to regedit. Then i will write this target platform on windows form screen

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: get target platform information and show it to the user